# Make image clickable to change it or add dedicated button

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad

I have a design question for iOS development. I am building this app where a user can set a profile picture and also "before/after"-pictures. From a design perspective, I wonder whether it is a good decision to make the images "clickable" as I display them on the screen so that the user only needs to tap on the image and then gets the possibility to change it or if it makes more sense to provide a dedicated button saying something like "Edit picture" / "Edit",... Maybe even do both? I am just wondering about the reasoning that each should be considered when deciding to go for the one or the other option...

Comment: Clicking on an image is often considered a "**View**" action, not and "**Edit**" one. So I would have an Edit button somewhere, even if it's only visible when you first View the image (by tapping on it).

Answer (score 1):

In Android there's no separate button which says "Edit Picture". You tap on the image to add a photo. But on iOS and some other mobile apps there's an "Edit" button available.

I'm an Android user and I didn't find any problems with the missing "Edit" button. But as @jgthms mentioned in some cases people will interpret this as a "View Full Image" rather than "Edit".

I personally think adding the text "Edit" will look ugly on a mobile app so I suggest something similar to Facebook. Like this,

[image: Edit Profile Image - Facebook.com]